# Can't import product in Magento with script

Tags: php, magento

I want to import product in magento. Here is the script:

```
<?php

$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$product->setSku("ABC123");
$product->setName("Name");
$product->setDescription("Desc.");
$product->setShortDescription("Desc2.");
$product->setPrice(70.50);
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setAttributeSetId(9); 
$product->setCategoryIds("20,24"); 
$product->setWeight(1.0);
$product->setTaxClassId(2);
$product->setVisibility(4); 
$product->setStatus(1); 

$product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));

$product->save();     

?>
```

The problem is the result:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`magento`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set`
>   (`attribute_set_i)' in
>   /home/zelewe3k/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /home/zelewe3k/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   /home/zelewe3k/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2
>   /home/zelewe3k/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291):
>   Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) #3
>   /home/zelewe3k/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4
>   /home/zelewe3k/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO`ca...', Array) #5
>   /home/zelewe3k/pu in
>   /home/zelewe3k/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234

What can I do?
How to fix it!?

Comment: If this is a new product, does attribute set `9` actually exist? If it's an existing product you *should* be able to change the attribute set - it's set to `CASCADE` on `DELETE` or `UPDATE` but I dread the think of the kind of mess that'll leave in the database. You'd probably be better off using *System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow Profiles*.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like  attribute set id 9 does not exist .Please check you attribute set id is exists in Magento or try

```
$product->setAttributeSetId(4);
```